# How to extract 2 bytes from a word, and how to make a word from 2 bytes (in C)?

Tags: c, byte, cpu-word

I am trying to extract two bytes from a 16-bit word, and to make a 16-bit word from two bytes. This is what I have tried (*byte = unsigned char, word = unsigned short*):

**Split grpix word into 2 bytes:**

```
word grpix; // Assume that the value has been initialized

byte grpixl = grpix & 0x00FF;
byte grpixh = grpix & 0xFF00;
```

**Make grpix word from 2 bytes**

```
byte grpixh; // Assume that the value has been initialized
byte grpixl; // Assume that the value has been initialized

word grpix = grpixh;
grpix <<= 8;
grpix += grpixl;
```

For some reason, my code doesn't work as expected, and now I'm not sure if the "splitting" of the word is wrong, if the "making" of the word is wrong, or both... Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Are you sure you're on a big endian machine? Intel chips are little-endian.

Comment: Big endian or small endian?

Comment: Well, my notebook has an Intel chip.

Comment: This StackOverflow entry may help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950366/how-do-i-convert-and-break-a-2-byte-integer-into-2-different-chars-in-c/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not shifting when you split the word. So if `grpix` is `0x1234`, then `grpixl` gets the expected `0x34` but `grpixh` ends up as `0x1200`. You should say

```
byte grpixh = grpix >> 8;
```

Of course, you're also ignoring any endianness concerns that may be present. You should probably convert your word to a known endian (with something like `htons()`) before attempting to split (and do the reverse conversion when joining).

Comment: I changed my code to this: `byte grpixh = (grpix >> 8) & 0x00FF;` and now it works :)

Answer (score 4):

Get to know: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html for doing all manner of operations.

```
right_byte = short_val & 0xFF;
left_byte = ( short_val >> 8 ) & 0xFF

short_val = ( ( left_byte & 0xFF ) << 8 ) | ( right_byte & 0xFF );
```

I always do a &0xFF mask to assure I have no sign problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you mask out the high byte, you need to also shift down by 8 bits, otherwise you just end up with a 16bit number with the bottom eight bits cleared.

```
byte grpixh = (grpix & 0xFF00) >> 8
```

Also your composition can be more efficient by using or-equals instead of plus-equals:

```
grpix |= grpixh << 8
```

Comment: In a 16-bit word, the mask here is pointless, because the bottom 8 bits will be discarded by the shift already.

Answer (score 0):

The simple code that I use to solve this, is:

```
word=(msb<<8)+lsb;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following routines have proved very reliable for me:-

```
unsigned short get16int(a) char *a;{
   unsigned short hi,lo;
   hi = *a++ << 8;
   lo = *a  & 0x00ff; /* Needed to cater for sign extending when msb bit is set */
   return (hi | lo);
}
put16int(a,i) char *a; int i;{
 *a++ = i >> 8;
 *a = i;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
word grpix = grpixl+256*grpixh;
```